# CSS Div content overlaps with other content

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with my CSS script. The content on my first `div` overlaps another `div` content.

I tried man solutions here, but it doesn't solve my problem

https://jsfiddle.net/ryuchix/89ws6xan/8/

**I know fixing the height will solve it. but I don't want it to be that way. because sometimes user inputs long text.**

HTML

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col col-md-12">
        <article>
            <ul id="c" class="awards-logo"> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                    <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>  
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                    <p>"Australian Entreprenuer and Author, George Konstand, launches new app for Entrepreneurs!</p>  
                </li> 

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                    <p>"Australian Entreprenuer and Author, George Konstand, launches new app for Entrepreneurs!</p>  
                </li> 

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                    <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>  
                </li> 

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                    <p>"Australian Entreprenuer and Author, George Konstand, launches new app for Entrepreneurs!</p>  
                </li> 

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                    <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>  
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
article{
  min-height: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

article > ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

article > ul > li {
  width: 25%;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px; 
  opacity: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s opacity; 
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

#c p { 
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px; 
  line-height: 1; 
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.awards-logo {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: inherit;
  padding: 50px;
}

.awards-logo li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1px 2px 0;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
}

.awards-logo li img{
  width: 180px
}

.screens-logo {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px;
}

.screens-logo li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1px 2px 0;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
}

.screens-logo li img{
  width: 180px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/89ws6xan/13/

```js
var timer = 4000;

var i = 0;
var max = $('#c > li').length;
 
    $("#c > li").eq(i).addClass('active').css('left','0');
    $("#c > li").eq(i + 1).addClass('active').css('left','25%');
    $("#c > li").eq(i + 2).addClass('active').css('left','50%');
    $("#c > li").eq(i + 3).addClass('active').css('left','75%');
 

    setInterval(function(){ 

        $("#c > li").removeClass('active');

        $("#c > li").eq(i).css('transition-delay','0.25s');
        $("#c > li").eq(i + 1).css('transition-delay','0.5s');
        $("#c > li").eq(i + 2).css('transition-delay','0.75s');
        $("#c > li").eq(i + 3).css('transition-delay','1s');

        if (i < max-4) {
            i = i+4; 
        }

        else { 
            i = 0; 
        }  

        $("#c > li").eq(i).css('left','0').addClass('active').css('transition-delay','1.25s');
        $("#c > li").eq(i + 1).css('left','25%').addClass('active').css('transition-delay','1.5s');
        $("#c > li").eq(i + 2).css('left','50%').addClass('active').css('transition-delay','1.75s');
        $("#c > li").eq(i + 3).css('left','75%').addClass('active').css('transition-delay','2s');
    
    }, timer);
```

```css
article{
  min-height: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

article > ul {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
  }
 
  article > ul > li {
    width: 25%;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px; 
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s opacity; 
  }

  .active {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  #c p { 
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 20px; 
    line-height: 1; 
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .awards-logo {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: inherit;
  padding: 50px;
}

.awards-logo li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1px 2px 0;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
}

.awards-logo li img{
  width: 180px

}

.screens-logo {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px;
}

.screens-logo li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1px 2px 0;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
}

.screens-logo li img{
  width: 180px

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" >
   <div class="col col-md-12">
    <article>
        <ul id="c" class="awards-logo"> 
            <li>
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                     <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>  
            </li> 
            <li>
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                     <p>"Australian Entreprenuer and Author, George Konstand, launches new app for Entrepreneurs!</p>  
            </li> 
            
            <li>
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                     <p>"Australian Entreprenuer and Author, George Konstand, launches new app for Entrepreneurs!</p>  
            </li> 
            
            <li>
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                     <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>  
            </li> 
            
            <li>
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                     <p>"Australian Entreprenuer and Author, George Konstand, launches new app for Entrepreneurs!</p>  
            </li> 
            
            <li>
                 <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></a>
                     <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>  
            </li> 
          </ul>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col col-md-12 screens"></div>
                <h1>Screens</h1>

             <ul class="screens-logo">
                  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
                  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
                  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
                  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
                </ul>

          </div>
```

Changed code

```
article > ul {
   position: relative;
   height: 250px;
}
```

As you are having 200px to absolute child element, you need to provide some pixel to parent relative element.

Comment: But to me if his content has a greater height than 250px, it will overlaps again, this is the problem with absolute positioning and customable content

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` remove the element of the normal flow. As you said, setting an height would fix the problem.

If your content length are variable you could try to calculate and set and height to each element through javacsript.

Another solution could be using `float` property on the list items and add a `clearfix` to the parent so it will keep the `height` value of your larger element (which will allow your user to write longer text).

**EDIT**

Here is a static example with `float` property.

https://jsfiddle.net/wollsale/L0ocjk9j/

```css
// Clearfix

%clearfix {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

// FIRST LIST

ul.first {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li.first__item {
  float: left;
  display: block;

  width: 25%;
}


// SECOND LIST

ul.second {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

li.second__item {
  float: left;
  display: block;

  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul class="first">
    <li class="first__item">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li class="first__item">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180">
        <p>Facere distinctio nostrum eius voluptas quae, blanditiis beatae illo totam officia adipisci tempora.</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="first__item">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati modi iusto doloribus nesciunt corporis dolor maxime fuga quaerat reprehenderit odio laudantium ullam animi, quidem accusantium in, consequatur veniam tempore odit! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem deserunt, veniam hic, aut accusantium illum, explicabo veritatis facilis delectus natus suscipit nostrum excepturi doloribus placeat similique numquam magni tenetur qui.</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="first__item">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180">
        <p>Doloremque maxime ab voluptas.</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="second">
    <li class="second__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
    <li class="second__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
    <li class="second__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
    <li class="second__item"><img src="http://placehold.it/260x180"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add height property and set its value as you need.**

```
.awards-logo {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: inherit;
      padding: 50px;
      height:300px
    }
```